# php integer inquiry about query string

Tags: php, integer, decimal

I have notifications coming in, I pass a price through the url

I seen someone put (integer) in front of the string like this:

```
$_paid = (integer)$_GET['paid']; // This is the amount paid. do I put (integer)$_GET... or (float)$_GET['
```

or is that (integer) just put there to show the example is an integer and php does not use that?

I'm not an experience php programmer, so I'm not sure if that would work, because paid would probably pass a number with a decimal in it.

Can you tell me how to best do this?

Thank you,
-Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are type casting. Usually a `$_GET` value is always a string or an array. If you want force `$_GET['paid']` to be a `float`, you can use `$_paid = (float) $_GET['paid'];`.

However a string in php can be evaluated in a numeric context, so, for example, `$paid = 5 + "5.5";` produces a `float`.

You can read about it from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: Thank you. Casting... and Juggling... that is what I needed to know. :) Appreciate it.